# UITableViewController reloadData cellForRowAtIndexPath not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

called loadData method from other viewcontoller like:

```
TestTVC *testTVC = [[TestTVC alloc] init];
[testTVC loadData];
```

I put `NSLog(@"testTVC Array section:%lu has %lu rows ")` in numberOfRowsInSection, it return result.

However in the cellForRowAtIndexPath section, the `NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath")` never printed for somehow.

I was sure that my delegate and data source were set properly. Because it works when `[self loadData]`

I also try run it in the main thread, it does't work.

Does anyone knows? Thanks.

updated: i used `[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];` instead of `[self.tableView reloaddata]`, it works but it didn't reload the UIImages in table cell.

```
NSLog(@"change cell image to testTVCImg1");
[testTVCCell.selectImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"testTVCImg1"]];
```

the NSLog debug message printed, but the image didn't changed.

Comment: What is your implementation of `loadData` ? And what is the result of `numberOfRowsInSection` ?

Comment: Insert  testTVC.delegate = self(or testTVC); and testTVC.datasource = self(or testTVC); in front of loadData method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called when a cell become visible.

When you do

```
TestTVC *testTVC = [[TestTVC alloc] init];
[testTVC loadData];
```

testTVC is not in the view hierarchy and its tableview neither. So `cellForRowAtIndexPath` won't be call.

Comment: Your update is no longer related to the previous question, it should be a new question. This way you'll be able to add more detail to this new question without damaging the previous one.